# Conditional Formatting and how it iterates

Tags: google-sheets

Ive been trying to get this to work properly, and I've used this custom formula plenty of times before with no issues.  The current issue I am facing is that the custom formatting seems eratic.  Some items are formatted that should be, some are formatted that shouldn't.  The only differences this time is two things.  1) I'm using it on several ranges, and 2) I am also using it on an `IMPORTRANGE`.

The formula meant to be looking for whether or not the content of a cell exists in a range of cells.  (If the contents of A5 exist in the range of $Y4:$AF16)

**Applys to Range**: `A5:A11,D10:D11,D5:D8,F5:F10,I4:I10,J7:J8,L5:L7,L9:L12,N5:N11,Q5:Q12,R7:R10,T5:U12,B20:E23,L20:M23,O20:P22,P23,A31:A36,C31:C37,E31:E32,E34:E35,F31:F34,H31:H34,J31:J35,K31:K41,M31:M33,P31:P32,Q31,S31:S34`

**The formula**:
`=COUNTIF($Y4:$AF16, A5)=0`

So I am thinking here that it's possible that my understanding of how conditional formatting goes through the range it applies to could be wrong.  Given the above range, my understanding is that it would go through each cell one-by-one.  For example, go through A5, A6, A7...A11, D10, D11, D5, D6, D7, D8...and so on.  Am I mistaken?  What do I need to do to make this work correctly?

`$Y4:$AF16` is an IMPORTRANGE from another sheet.  I would have expected some delay but I don't think this would break anything.

**Update:** Even when reduced to a simple range `A5:A11`, it still has the same erratic behavior.  Here is a link to the sheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rg_lsgVWXC6C1e4LVhqqp2kOSLDOG56FqVqChWbBTyI/edit?usp=sharing

Also, if I copy the importrange and paste the values, then use that range, it's still erratic.  I have to assume I am doing something wrong in the formula and\or misunderstanding conditional formatting.

I tested individual cells myself with `=COUNTIF(Y4:AF16,A5)`, `=COUNTIF(Y4:AF16,A6)`, `=COUNTIF(Y4:AF16,A7)`, etc. and that worked appropriately.  Down to how the conditional formatting iterates through cells I guess, which I guess I don't understand anymore.

Comment: FWIW it seems legit in my eyes. Is there anything in the importrange data types that could be messing with this?

Comment: @a-burge Everything in the range is a string.  I don't really know.  I'll add a link to a copy of the sheet.

Comment: I just thought of one thing. It seems the conditional formatting doesn't like fixing the reference to the importrange table (for A5:A11 it works when removing the dollar signs). You could try naming the range and referring to it instead of the range itself. That could work, at least worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

1. Name the importrange area (Y4:AF16) to e.g. Roster (Data -> Named ranges)
2. Change the conditional formatting to refer to the named range: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Roster"),A5)=0`. The indirect forces it to look for that range.

Comment: I don't know why this worked, but it did.  It's strange to me because I've done this many many times before on other sheets using fixed cell references without any issues.  Oh well, thanks a lot!